# Why I am keeping to get an exception of java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene50/Lucene50Codec

Tags: lucene

I am using Lucene 5.4 and recently want to migrate a project to spring framework.

If I invoke my indexing code in a java main function it works no errors, but when deploy the code on Tomcat 9.0, it comes with the following error. The WEB-INF/lib folder has four Lucene jars, which are lucene-core-5.4.0.jar, lucene-facet-5.4.0.jar, lucene-queries-5.4.0.jar and lucene-queryparser-5.4.0.jar. I think these four jars should be enough for document indexing, right? Also I am using lucent 5.4, why the code try to find Lucene50Codec class rather than Lucene54Codec class?

```
Tomcat Exception report

message Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene50/Lucene50Codec

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene50/Lucene50Codec
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1302)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:977)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene50/Lucene50Codec
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.reload(NamedSPILoader.java:67)
    org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:47)
    org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.<init>(NamedSPILoader.java:37)
    org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec$Holder.<clinit>(Codec.java:47)
    org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec.getDefault(Codec.java:140)
    org.apache.lucene.index.LiveIndexWriterConfig.<init>(LiveIndexWriterConfig.java:120)
    org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.<init>(IndexWriterConfig.java:140)
    com.zhaoyun.r3ds.core.lucene.LuceneFactoryImpl.createWriter(LuceneFactoryImpl.java:113)
    com.zhaoyun.r3ds.core.engine.SearchEngineImpl.getImageWriter(SearchEngineImpl.java:87)
    com.zhaoyun.r3ds.core.engine.ImageEngine.addImageDocument(ImageEngine.java:50)
    com.zhaoyun.r3ds.restful.controller.SemanticController.index(SemanticController.java:43)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Answer (score 2):

The index might have been written with an earlier version of Lucene and the coded is no longer available in Lucene 5.4.
You need to include the [lucene-backward-codecs-5.4.0.jar](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.lucene|lucene-backward-codecs|5.4.0|jar) file as well.

Alternatively, you might have multiple versions of Lucene in Tomcats classpath where some are of Version 5.0 and some are of version 5.4. You should make sure, that there is only one version of Lucene on the classpath of Tomcat.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the issue for me.

Comment: @knutwalker hi, can you be more specific - where should the lucene-backward-codecs-5.4.0.jar be included? which folder?

Comment: The jar should be somewhere on your classpath. Where exactly that is depends on your deployment, it might be a folder called `lib` or something similar or you might have to change the executed java command to include the jar in the `-classpath` argument.